# Codeigniter mysql like query not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter query with the following lines.

```
$userloc=$this->session->userdata('location');
$query=$this->db->query('select assettype,sum(status="In Stock")In_stock,sum(status = "Allocated")Allocated,sum(status = "Decommission")Decommission,sum(status = "In transit")In_Transit,location from assets group by assettype,location');
```

i want to put a like condition in the `$query` where `location like $userloc` but its not working as expected.

Comment: sooo... **where** is your WHERE? we can't debug code you don't show.

Comment: Improved title, added code blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below

```
$this->db->select('assettype,sum(status="In Stock")In_stock,sum(status =  "Allocated")Allocated,sum(status = "Decommission") Decommission,sum(status = "In transit")In_Transit,location');
$this->db->from('assets');
$this->db->like('location', $userloc);
$this->db->group_by('assettype,location');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$userloc = $this->session->userdata('location');

$query = $this->db->query('select assettype, sum(status="In Stock") In_stock,
sum(status = "Allocated") Allocated,
sum(status = "Decommission") Decommission,
sum(status = "In transit") In_Transit,
location from assets where  location like "%'.$userloc.'%" group by assettype,location');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

`$query=$this->db->query('select assettype,sum(status="In Stock")In_stock,sum(status = "Allocated")Allocated,sum(status = "Decommission")Decommission,sum(status = "In transit")In_Transit,location from assets where location like %$userloc% group by assettype,location');`

Answer (score 0):

use following Query

```
$userloc=$this->session->userdata('location');

$query=$this->db->query('select assettype,sum(status="In Stock")In_stock,sum(status = "Allocated")Allocated,sum(status = "Decommission")Decommission,sum(status = "In transit")In_Transit,location from assets where location like '%$userloc%' group by assettype,location');
```